# Registering plugin on quick find in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have to register a plugin on Quick Find search on "Artilce" entity. When user enter any thing in quick find text box on Article entity at that time my plugin execute and return filter the data based on our business logic.
 1.What event is fired when we find using quick find.
 2.What message passes when this event is fired.

I have tried registering the plugin on RetrieveMultiple message but this is not triggered when we click on search in quick find.

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408685/crm-2011-intercepting-the-quick-search-fetch-xml-and-query-expression-dont-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have raised a ticket with Microsoft to address this situaation.
The solution they provided was to modify the Database to make the message
**SearchByTitleKbArticleRequest** available in the plugin registration tool.

I currently dont remember the table that we updated a flag against these messages.

After updating the table we were able to register the plugin against the message

**SearchByTitleKbArticleRequest**

Then the plugin triggered and we modified the entity collection returned from there.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Plugin registered on the RetrieveMultiple. We had a business requirement to search for the records, using WildCard by default.

**Plugin Registration Details:**

`Message: RetrieveMultiple`

`Primary Entity:None`

`Secondary Entity:None`

`Pre-Operation`

**Code:**

```
public const String QueryLiteral = "Query";
    public const String LIKE = "%";
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        String ParentEntity = String.Empty;
        String OriginalSearch = String.Empty;

        // Obtain the execution context from the service provider. 
        var ContextInstance = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        // Get a reference to the Organization service. 
        IOrganizationService ServiceInstance =
            ((IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory))).
                CreateOrganizationService(ContextInstance.InitiatingUserId);
        // Critical Point here - NOTICE that the InputParameters Contains the word Query
        if (ContextInstance.Depth < 2 && ContextInstance.InputParameters.Contains(QueryLiteral) &&
               ContextInstance.InputParameters[QueryLiteral] is QueryExpression)
        {
            QueryExpression QueryPointer = (ContextInstance.InputParameters[QueryLiteral] as QueryExpression);
            //Verify the conversion worked as expected - if not, everything else is useless
            if (null != QueryPointer)
            {
                // Check if the request is coming from any Search View 
                // We know this b/c Criteria isn't null and the Filters Count > 1
                if (null != QueryPointer.Criteria && QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters.Count > 1)
                {
                    ParentEntity = ContextInstance.PrimaryEntityName;
                    OriginalSearch = QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[1].Conditions[0].Values[0].ToString();
                    OriginalSearch = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                     "{0}{1}", LIKE, OriginalSearch);
                }
                ConditionExpression NewCondition = null;
                FilterExpression NewFilter = null;
                if (null != QueryPointer.Criteria)
                {
                    //Change the default 'BeginsWith'Operator to 'Contains/Like' operator in the basic search query
                    foreach (FilterExpression FilterSet in QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters)
                    {
                        foreach (ConditionExpression ConditionSet in FilterSet.Conditions)
                        {
                            if (ConditionSet.Operator == ConditionOperator.Like)
                            {
                                if (OriginalSearch != "")
                                    ConditionSet.Values[0] = OriginalSearch;
                                else
                                {
                                    OriginalSearch = QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions[0].Values[0].ToString();
                                    OriginalSearch = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                     "{0}{1}", LIKE, OriginalSearch);
                                    ConditionSet.Values[0] = OriginalSearch;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ContextInstance.InputParameters[QueryLiteral] = QueryPointer;
        }
 }
```

Check details on this Post: http://www.williamgryan.mobi/?p=596

Comment: Thank for your response. But even registering against  Entity:None, the plugin is not triggered.

Comment: @AnandKumarM have you debug the plugin ??
if you cannot debug the plugin, you can simply throw an exception inside execute method, to check if plugin is triggered.

We have deployed this plugin on prod and working fine.

Comment: Yes I debugged the plugin. Retrieve Multiple Plugin is fired for  other entities (account,opportunity,contact ) when we use Quick find. but for KBArticle it is not triggering.